# PostgreSQL query joining with view has poor performance

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create an API that returns the list of files/folders that the user owns, similar to Google Drive. The information about user's files/folders/other is stored in the PostgreSQL tables.

I have created a view called gc_drive that gets the file list from these tables. Yes, I call them tables because there are different tables for files, folders, and virtual files so I use a view to join all these records together so they effectively appear as a file system, even though they are not 100% a file system.

The view performance looks fine, I have indexed the necessary columns and even though the view has more than 2.7 million records with all the data combined, it filters by ID and it returns the filtered records by a parent in milliseconds. However, if I try to select count(*) from gc_drive it takes 69 seconds because the base tables that contain the list of files, folders, resources and other have more than 7 million records each.

I want to join the gc_drive view with the fn_resource_permissions table that has info on whether the user has access to the resource.

When I use the following query to get the current logged in user's permissions the records return almost instantly:

```
select*from 
fn_resource_permissions
WHERE ((fn_resource_permissions.permission_id IN (23,
                                                  24,
                                                  25,
                                                  37,
                                                  36)
AND (fn_resource_permissions.user_id = 2
     OR fn_resource_permissions.user_id = 1)))

--59 records returned
```

The query above returns me all the permissions to the resources that the user has. I will use those records to filter the gc_drive view.

When I try to use these 59 records in the following query to filter out the gc_drive view the records also return instantly:

```
SELECT gc_drive.id,
       "fn_resources"."owner_id" AS "fn_resources.owner_id",
       "gc_drive".*
FROM "gc_drive"
JOIN "fn_resources" ON ("gc_drive"."resource_id" = "fn_resources"."id")
WHERE "fn_resources"."archived" = 0
AND   gc_drive.id IN(
    1234,
    1235,
    1236,
    ...
);
```

The problem is when I try to join the 2 queries above together:

```
SELECT gc_drive.id,
       "fn_resources"."owner_id" AS "fn_resources.owner_id",
       "gc_drive".*
FROM "gc_drive"
JOIN "fn_resources" ON ("gc_drive"."resource_id" = "fn_resources"."id")
JOIN "fn_resource_permissions" ON ("fn_resource_permissions"."resource_id" = fn_resources.id)
WHERE "fn_resources"."archived" = 0
AND ((fn_resource_permissions.permission_id IN (23,
                                                24,
                                                25,
                                                37,
                                                36)
          AND (fn_resource_permissions.user_id = 2
               OR fn_resource_permissions.user_id = 1)))
LIMIT 101;
```

When I look in the Explain plan, I can see that the PostgreSQL is materializing the whole gc_drive view, and only then is trying to filter by resource permissions. This makes the query run in minutes, not in milliseconds. I have also tried to put the resource permissions in with clause and it does the same. I know that one of the solutions could be to separate each user's content in its own schema but I want to know if there is a better more efficient way to join the gc_drive view and other tables without PostgreSQL first materializing the whole view. Is there a way to modify the query so that PostgreSQL can filter only on the whole set of records.

Explain analyze plan on the above query:

```
    ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                                       │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Limit  (cost=4845.56..57547586.51 rows=101 width=722) (actual time=201371.236..201371.236 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                             │
│   ->  Hash Join  (cost=4845.56..681971785.33 rows=1197 width=722) (actual time=201371.234..201371.234 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                 │
│         Hash Cond: ("*SELECT* 1".resource_id = fn_resources.id)                                                                                                                       │
│         ->  Append  (cost=36.10..681748786.17 rows=15867640 width=247) (actual time=17521.979..200235.975 rows=2737742 loops=1)                                                       │
│               ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=36.10..533636.75 rows=11252 width=150) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)                                               │
│                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=36.10..533524.23 rows=11252 width=150) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)                                                             │
│                           Hash Cond: (fnr_child.type = fnrt.type)                                                                                                                     │
│                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..66613.04 rows=1940 width=122) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)                                                        │
│                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..49607.76 rows=1940 width=100) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)                                                  │
│                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..32602.48 rows=1940 width=104) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)                                            │
│                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16315.94 rows=1940 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)                                       │
│                                                   ->  Seq Scan on gc_virtual_file gvf  (cost=0.00..29.40 rows=1940 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)                 │
│                                                   ->  Index Scan using gc_file_resource_id_key on gc_file gf_child  (cost=0.00..8.38 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)                 │
│                                                         Index Cond: (resource_id = gvf.resource_id)                                                                                   │
│                                             ->  Index Scan using gc_file_resource_id_key on gc_file gf_parent  (cost=0.00..8.38 rows=1 width=92) (never executed)                     │
│                                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = gvf.parent_id)                                                                                           │
│                                       ->  Index Scan using fn_resources_pkey on fn_resources fnr_parent  (cost=0.00..8.75 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)                            │
│                                             Index Cond: (id = gvf.parent_id)                                                                                                          │
│                                 ->  Index Scan using fn_resources_pkey on fn_resources fnr_child  (cost=0.00..8.75 rows=1 width=30) (never executed)                                  │
│                                       Index Cond: (id = gvf.resource_id)                                                                                                              │
│                           ->  Hash  (cost=21.60..21.60 rows=1160 width=36) (never executed)                                                                                           │
│                                 ->  Seq Scan on fn_resource_types fnrt  (cost=0.00..21.60 rows=1160 width=36) (never executed)                                                        │
│                           SubPlan 6                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on fn_users  (cost=0.00..8.28 rows=1 width=13) (never executed)                                                           │
│                                   Index Cond: (id = fnr_child.owner_id)                                                                                                               │
│                           SubPlan 7                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_tables_resource_id_key on gc_tables gt  (cost=0.00..8.28 rows=1 width=18) (never executed)                                        │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│                           SubPlan 8                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_webmapservices_resource_id_key on gc_webmapservices gwms  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=418) (never executed)                     │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│                           SubPlan 9                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_tables_resource_id_key on gc_tables gt  (cost=0.00..8.31 rows=1 width=14) (never executed)                                        │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│                           SubPlan 10                                                                                                                                                  │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_webmapservices_resource_id_key on gc_webmapservices gwms  (cost=0.00..8.30 rows=1 width=267) (never executed)                     │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│               ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=580092.62..681215149.42 rows=15856388 width=247) (actual time=17521.724..199482.039 rows=2737742 loops=1)                      │
│                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=580092.62..681056585.54 rows=15856388 width=247) (actual time=17521.668..198482.521 rows=2737742 loops=1)                                    │
│                           Hash Cond: (fnr_child.type = fnrt.type)                                                                                                                     │
│                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=580056.53..1189954.39 rows=2733860 width=219) (actual time=16768.431..88474.618 rows=2737742 loops=1)                                  │
│                                 Hash Cond: (gf_parent.resource_id = fnr_parent.id)                                                                                                    │
│                                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=388738.70..943959.36 rows=2733860 width=219) (actual time=13619.604..72625.523 rows=2737742 loops=1)                             │
│                                       Hash Cond: (gf_child.path = gf_parent.pathname)                                                                                                 │
│                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=202378.85..538142.64 rows=2733860 width=168) (actual time=6429.263..53255.517 rows=2737743 loops=1)                        │
│                                             Hash Cond: (fnr_child.id = gf_child.resource_id)                                                                                          │
│                                             ->  Seq Scan on fn_resources fnr_child  (cost=0.00..114415.70 rows=6152170 width=30) (actual time=21.243..19364.289 rows=6119914 loops=1) │
│                                             ->  Hash  (cost=112139.60..112139.60 rows=2733860 width=142) (actual time=5666.626..5666.626 rows=2737743 loops=1)                        │
│                                                   Buckets: 262144  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 240441kB                                                                                 │
│                                                   ->  Seq Scan on gc_file gf_child  (cost=0.00..112139.60 rows=2733860 width=142) (actual time=0.015..3442.788 rows=2737751 loops=1)  │
│                                       ->  Hash  (cost=112139.60..112139.60 rows=2733860 width=92) (actual time=7173.094..7173.094 rows=2737751 loops=1)                               │
│                                             Buckets: 262144  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 169423kB                                                                                       │
│                                             ->  Seq Scan on gc_file gf_parent  (cost=0.00..112139.60 rows=2733860 width=92) (actual time=0.007..5057.412 rows=2737751 loops=1)        │
│                                 ->  Hash  (cost=114415.70..114415.70 rows=6152170 width=4) (actual time=3145.424..3145.424 rows=6119914 loops=1)                                      │
│                                       Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 215154kB                                                                                            │
│                                       ->  Seq Scan on fn_resources fnr_parent  (cost=0.00..114415.70 rows=6152170 width=4) (actual time=0.008..1186.819 rows=6119914 loops=1)         │
│                           ->  Hash  (cost=21.60..21.60 rows=1160 width=36) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=21 loops=1)                                                                 │
│                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB                                                                                                          │
│                                 ->  Seq Scan on fn_resource_types fnrt  (cost=0.00..21.60 rows=1160 width=36) (actual time=0.005..0.012 rows=21 loops=1)                              │
│                           SubPlan 1                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on fn_users  (cost=0.00..8.28 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=2737742)                            │
│                                   Index Cond: (id = fnr_child.owner_id)                                                                                                               │
│                           SubPlan 2                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_file_resource_id_key on gc_file gf  (cost=0.00..8.62 rows=1 width=47) (never executed)                                            │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│                           SubPlan 3                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_file_resource_id_key on gc_file gf  (cost=0.00..8.62 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=2665337)             │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│                           SubPlan 4                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_file_resource_id_key on gc_file gf  (cost=0.00..8.63 rows=1 width=129) (never executed)                                           │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│                           SubPlan 5                                                                                                                                                   │
│                             ->  Index Scan using gc_file_resource_id_key on gc_file gf  (cost=0.00..8.66 rows=1 width=145) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=2665337)            │
│                                   Index Cond: (resource_id = fnr_child.id)                                                                                                            │
│         ->  Hash  (cost=4804.79..4804.79 rows=374 width=12) (actual time=412.434..412.434 rows=59 loops=1)                                                                            │
│               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3kB                                                                                                                            │
│               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=13.32..4804.79 rows=374 width=12) (actual time=156.510..412.313 rows=59 loops=1)                                                                 │
│                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on fn_resource_permissions  (cost=13.32..1454.38 rows=374 width=4) (actual time=155.407..402.734 rows=59 loops=1)                            │
│                           Recheck Cond: ((user_id = 2) OR (user_id = 1))                                                                                                              │
│                           Filter: (permission_id = ANY ('{23,24,25,37,36}'::integer[]))                                                                                               │
│                           ->  BitmapOr  (cost=13.32..13.32 rows=391 width=0) (actual time=88.402..88.402 rows=0 loops=1)                                                              │
│                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resource_permissions_user  (cost=0.00..6.57 rows=196 width=0) (actual time=88.380..88.380 rows=61 loops=1)                   │
│                                       Index Cond: (user_id = 2)                                                                                                                       │
│                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resource_permissions_user  (cost=0.00..6.57 rows=196 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)                      │
│                                       Index Cond: (user_id = 1)                                                                                                                       │
│                     ->  Index Scan using fn_resources_pkey on fn_resources  (cost=0.00..8.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.154..0.155 rows=1 loops=59)                               │
│                           Index Cond: (id = fn_resource_permissions.resource_id)                                                                                                      │
│                           Filter: (archived = 0)                                                                                                                                      │
│ Total runtime: 201373.236 ms                                                                                                                                                          │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe partitioning by user ?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You have added the plan generated using `explain`  - please show us the plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added the query plan. I am thinking that the best and only scenario in this case could be to split the data from the tables into each user schema.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is structured so that`fn_resources` is filtered by `fn_resource_permissions` and then joined onto `gc_drive`, despite the same data being present in `gc_drive`.

This is a little bit of a hunch, but try filtering `gc_drive` by `fn_resource_permissions` early with the `where` clause, rather than a join on a join.

```
select
    gc_drive.id,
    fn_resources.owner_id,
    gc_drive.*
from
    gc_drive
    join fn_resources on(
        gc_drive.resource_id = fn_resources.id
    )
where
    gc_drive.resource_id in(
        select
            fn_resource_permissions.resource_id
        from
            fn_resource_permissions
        where
            fn_resource_permissions.permission_id in (23, 24, 25, 37, 36)
            and fn_resource_permissions.user_id in(1, 2)
    )
    and fn_resources.archived = 0
limit 101;
```

Alternativley, try filtering `fn_resources` before the join

```
select
    gc_drive.id,
    fn_resources.owner_id,
    gc_drive.*
from
    gc_drive
    join fn_resources on(
        gc_drive.resource_id = fn_resources.id
        and fn_resources.id in(
            select
                fn_resource_permissions.resource_id
            from
                fn_resource_permissions
            where
                fn_resource_permissions.permission_id in (23, 24, 25, 37, 36)
                and fn_resource_permissions.user_id in(1, 2)
        )
    )
where
    fn_resources.archived = 0
limit 101;
```